# How to disable all repositories using yum module in ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, yum

I'm trying to disable all the yum repos and enable just 1 repo for installing a yum package.How to disable all repos using yum module?

Tried to use disablerepo='*' but not sure whether this is the correct method

```
- name: Update the uek kernel pkg on gateways
    yum:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      disablerepo: "*"
      enablerepo: test_iso
    vars:
      packages:
      - kernel-uek
    become_user: root
```

Comment: what was the outcome of the trial? Any error ?

Comment: Didn't got any error.But just want to know whether this is correct way to disable all repos?

Comment: Ohk..the list way was easily there in ansible docs to refer. But your question was to delete all the repos using wild card which is not supported may be you can apply some logic and generate the list dynamically and pass it the yum module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) suggests you must supply a comma-separated list of repo ids.

> **disablerepo**: Repoid of repositories to disable for the install/update operation. These repos will not persist beyond the transaction. When specifying multiple repos, separate them with a ",".
>   As of Ansible 2.7, this can alternatively be a list instead of "," separated string

The example from the documentation:

```
- name: Install package with multiple repos disabled
  yum:
    name: sos
    disablerepo: "epel,ol7_latest"
```

You might look into using the [yum_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html) module as an alternative as well:

```
# Example removing a repository and cleaning up metadata cache
- name: Remove repository (and clean up left-over metadata)
  yum_repository:
    name: epel
    state: absent
  notify: yum-clean-metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nick pointed out, the current yum module requires us to provide a list of specific repository names.

We can use `yum -q repolist` to query and parse the list of repositories.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Get list of yum repos (to disable them temporarily)
    ansible.builtin.command: yum -q repolist
    register: _yum_repolist_output
    changed_when: False

  - name: Install Docker RPMs
    yum:
      name: "http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/vim-enhanced-7.4.629-7.el7.x86_64.rpm"
      enablerepo: []
      disablerepo: "{{ _yum_repolist_output.stdout_lines[1:] | map('split',' ') | map('first') | list }}"
```

This is not an ideal solution, but it seems to be the only solution to use the `yum` module in a setup with broken repository configuration, e.g. on air-gap systems.